# Animate Images in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, animation, uialertview

I am trying to play an animation of images in a `UIAlertView`.

Here is my code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIImageView *animation = nil;
animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Comment-Edit-48.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Share-48.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Comment-Edit-48.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play-48.png"], nil];
[animation setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
animation.animationDuration = 1.5;
[animation startAnimating];

[alert addSubview:animation];


[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Can anyone please tell me what I did wrong here ?

Comment: First, you need to tell us what wrong with code of yours.

Comment: @HelmiB The animation didn't show in the UIAlertView. But it works now. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to your animation imageView frame size. You need to alloc it with certain frame size of your animation imageView. If you don't do that then it will not occupy any memory space. A nil object would have been add inside UIAlertView. Try this below given code

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIImageView *animation =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 50, 50, 45)];
animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Comment-Edit-48.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Share-48.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Comment-Edit-48.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play-48.png"], nil];
[animation setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
animation.animationDuration = 1.5;
[animation startAnimating];

[alert addSubview:animation];


[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Set this frame size and it works fine. I hope it will help you. Thanks

Comment: Hi RuckSackJoe, Thanks for reply. I have implemented it at my end. It's working fine. If still it is not working then please check your image name . Please have a look on my updated code